# How to get entity through a link table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Somebody edit the join table, because I can't remember the word for a table that contains only 2 foreign keys for 2 entities. Edit: I think it's called a link table?

The db-model looks like this [DB-Model entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE9MI.png). And in the code for the models and DTO's, datadock has a `List<Standard>`. So the code looks like this:

```
    private List<DatadockDTO> GetDatadocksByDataportId(Guid id)
    {
        var query = from r in _ddRepository.GetIQueryable()
                    where r.DataportId == id
                    select new DatadockDTO
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name,                            
                        Standards = r.Standards //Error not possible, the only suggestion it gives is DataDockStandards
                        //I used to put GetStandardsByDatadockId(r.Id) here but there is another way apparently
                    };
        List<DatadockDTO> datadocks = query.ToList();
        return datadocks;
    }
```

But somebody I work with told me Entity Framework allows you to do something like that. But I'm not sure where to look for.

The extra code I made how I **thought** it was supposed to work:

```
    private List<StandardDTO> GetStandardsByDatadockId(int id)
    {
        var query = from r in _standardRepository.GetIQueryable()
                    where r.DataDockStandards.Any(dds => dds.DatadockId == id)
                    select new StandardDTO
                    {
                        Id = r.Id,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        StandardVersions = GetStandardVersionsByStandardId(r.Id)
                    };
        List<StandardDTO> standards = query.ToList();
        return standards;
    }

    private List<StandardVersionDTO> GetStandardVersionsByStandardId(int id)
    {
        var query =
          from r in _svRepository.GetIQueryable()
          where r.StandardId == id
          select new StandardVersionDTO
          {
              Id = r.Id,
              Name = r.Name,
          };
        List<StandardVersionDTO> versions = query.ToList();
        return versions;
    }
```

EDIT (next day): okay so apparently somehow I **can** select r.Standards somehow. I didn't change anything, I could suddenly just choose r.Standards without getting an error...

Comment: Your code is a black box. We don't know the result of these `GetIQueryable` calls. Also, it's not clear what you're actually asking. You show code, but what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure many-to-many relationship.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) is how it's done in EF Core (keep in mind, it's only for version 5 and above, it is not supported even in 3.1).

And [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) is how it's done in EF 6.

If you do it correctly, your `DataDock` entity will have `Standards` navigation property and you'll be able to use it in LINQ queries.